# npm install globally a package offline with tarball

Tags: node.js, offline-files, npm

According to [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), this should work;

```
npm install ./package.tgz
```

So I try this globally for pm2 tarfile I have downloaded from [pm2 github repo releases page](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/releases);

```
npm install -g ./pm2-3.2.2.tar.gz
```

But I got this;

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@pm2%2fagent failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND nb nb:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-01-29T08_16_17_112Z-debug.log
```

-

```
npm version: 5.6.0
node version: 9.4.0
```

Is it a bug?

Is there any other way to install pm2 (and any other) package offline?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295050/how-to-install-npm-g-on-offline-server#comment14859884_11295323

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I need to take care of the dependencies of the package as well. I got the solution in this answer of [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295050/how-to-install-npm-g-on-offline-server);

> Well.... after a day trying to make it work with above references
>   (npmbox or offline-npm) came up with something way much simpler.
>   Thanks to npmbox I have to say. The idea is the keep the cache from
>   the instance that has online access and then use it in the one
>   offline.
>
> In machine with internet:
>
> 1 - clear npm cache: npm cache clear
>
> 2 - install package, lets say its x.y.z: npm install -g
>   **package.x.y.z**
>
> 3 - copy cache in to a folder... let's call it whatever (I assume npm
>   cache is in root folder, not absolutely sure about that):  cp -R
>   /.npm/* **/cache-whatever-folder**
>
> In machine with no internet:
>
> 4 - take this cache-whatever-folder to the instance with no internet
>   and after that, clean cache and install with it (I won't indicate how
>   to copy the folder :)
>
> npm cache clear
>
> npm install --global --cache **/cache-whatever-folder** --optional
>   --cache-min 99999999999 --shrinkwrap false **package.x.y.z**
>
> Done

Answer link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43793301/169534

Comment: I'll be wary of your method. `npm cache` has this to say on their docs: "npm makes *no guarantee* that a previously-cached piece of data will be available later". So your cache may be incomplete or corrupted.